# How does sudo!! work on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, sudo

I love the idea behind the command:

```
sudo!!
```

but it doesn't really work on ubuntu (14.04 and earlier).

When I type

```
apt-get install htop
```

It will obviously tells me to run the command as super user. And therefore I should be able to run this:

```
sudo!!
```

which would execute the command

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

but instead it tells me that it couldn't find the command

```
sudoapt-get
```

Which basically means that it doesn't put a space after the sudo keyword. Why is that? Am I using the command wrong? I am very certain that I get the expected behaviour on Fedora.

Comment: Probably Fedora is so clever that put spaces where you are too lazy to use them. :)  ...Don't be so certain; this probability is 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's

```
sudo !!
```

and not

```
sudo!!
```

Bash expands the `!!` exactly - it doesn't add spaces where there were none.